# omniauth-facebook-access-token not accepting new FB user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth, devise, omniauth, facebook-oauth

I am using rails 4.1.6 and ruby 2.1.3 and omniauth-facebook-access-token 0.1.6.

I am POSTing to /users/auth/facebook_access_token/callback with access_token set to the FB user's access token. Here is the error I get.

```
AbstractController::ActionNotFound (The action 'facebook_access_token' could not be found for Users::OmniauthCallbacksController):
  actionpack (4.1.6) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:131:in `process'
  actionview (4.1.6) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
  actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:196:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:232:in `block in action'
  actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:82:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:82:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:50:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:45:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:73:in `block in call'
  actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `each'
  actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:678:in `call'
  omniauth (1.2.2) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:404:in `call_app!'
  omniauth-facebook-access-token (0.1.6) lib/omniauth/strategies/facebook-access-token.rb:100:in `callback_phase'
  omniauth (1.2.2) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:227:in `callback_call'
  omniauth (1.2.2) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:184:in `call!'
  omniauth (1.2.2) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:164:in `call'
  omniauth (1.2.2) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:404:in `call_app!'
  omniauth-facebook-access-token (0.1.6) lib/omniauth/strategies/facebook-access-token.rb:100:in `callback_phase'
  omniauth (1.2.2) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:227:in `callback_call'
  omniauth (1.2.2) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:184:in `call!'
  omniauth (1.2.2) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:164:in `call'
  omniauth (1.2.2) lib/omniauth/builder.rb:59:in `call'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:35:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:254:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
  activerecord (4.1.6) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
  activerecord (4.1.6) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:621:in `call'
  activerecord (4.1.6) lib/active_record/migration.rb:380:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:82:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.1.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.1.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.1.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:26:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
  railties (4.1.6) lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
  railties (4.1.6) lib/rails/application.rb:144:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
  /home/eric/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  /home/eric/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  /home/eric/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
```

I have added the following to my config/initializers/devise.rb because if I don't, there is no middleware loaded:

```
config.omniauth :facebook_access_token, ENV['FACEBOOK_KEY'], ENV['FACEBOOK_SECRET']
```

I have added the following to my config/initializers/omniauth.rb as per the documentation:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :facebook_access_token, ENV['FACEBOOK_KEY'], ENV['FACEBOOK_SECRET']
end
```

Here are my routes:

```
                  Prefix Verb     URI Pattern                            Controller#Action
        new_user_session GET      /users/sign_in(.:format)               devise/sessions#new
            user_session POST     /users/sign_in(.:format)               devise/sessions#create
    destroy_user_session DELETE   /users/sign_out(.:format)              devise/sessions#destroy
 user_omniauth_authorize GET|POST /users/auth/:provider(.:format)        users/omniauth_callbacks#passthru {:provider=>/facebook_access_token/}
  user_omniauth_callback GET|POST /users/auth/:action/callback(.:format) users/omniauth_callbacks#:action
           user_password POST     /users/password(.:format)              devise/passwords#create
       new_user_password GET      /users/password/new(.:format)          devise/passwords#new
      edit_user_password GET      /users/password/edit(.:format)         devise/passwords#edit
                         PATCH    /users/password(.:format)              devise/passwords#update
                         PUT      /users/password(.:format)              devise/passwords#update
cancel_user_registration GET      /users/cancel(.:format)                devise/registrations#cancel
       user_registration POST     /users(.:format)                       devise/registrations#create
   new_user_registration GET      /users/sign_up(.:format)               devise/registrations#new
  edit_user_registration GET      /users/edit(.:format)                  devise/registrations#edit
                         PATCH    /users(.:format)                       devise/registrations#update
                         PUT      /users(.:format)                       devise/registrations#update
                         DELETE   /users(.:format)                       devise/registrations#destroy
                    home GET      /home(.:format)                        redirect(301, /)
                    root GET      /                                      high_voltage/pages#show {:id=>"home"}
                    page GET      /pages/*id                             high_voltage/pages#show
```

Comment: Can you post routes.rb?

Comment: can you post controller code as well?

Comment: Thanks man, you led me to my issue. I had defined Users::OmniauthCallbacksController#facebook but not Users::OmniauthCallbacksController#facebook_access_token.

Comment: After looking at your error and routes, i had a hunch that it could be this but wanted to confirm. Anyways glad to hear that it worked for you :)

Answer (score 1):

I had defined `Users::OmniauthCallbacksController#facebook` but not `Users::OmniauthCallbacksController#facebook_access_token`. It works now!